# SharedPreferances in Spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-sharedpreferences

i have a probleme with sharedpreferances in spinners, i have 2 spinners, i want to save my spinners with shared preferances i can save the first spinner but i can't save the second one, sombody can help me please
thanks to all.
i have a probleme with sharedpreferances in spinners, i have 2 spinners, i want to save my spinners with shared preferances i can save the first spinner but i can't save the second one, sombody can help me please
thanks to all.

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String india[]={"humains","elfes","hobbits"};
    String m[]={"PUNE","Mumbai","yoo"};
    String b[]={"Arwen","Elrond","Galadriel","Legolas"};
    String u[]={"sup","trankill","Conor","Mcgregor","Nate Diaz"};

    Spinner s,s1,s2;
    private Button btnSubmit;
   SharedPreferences mypref;
    final String KEY_SavedSel = "Saved Selection";
    final String KEY_SavedSe2 = "Saved Selection";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_android_app);
        s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);



        final ArrayAdapter<String>ia=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,india);

        final ArrayAdapter<String>ma=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,m);

        final ArrayAdapter<String>ba=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,b);

        final ArrayAdapter<String>ua=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,u);

        ia.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(ia);
        mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int prefsInt = mypref.getInt(KEY_SavedSel, -1);
        int prefsInt1 = mypref.getInt(KEY_SavedSe2,-1);
        if(prefsInt != -1){
            s.setSelection(prefsInt);

        }

        if(prefsInt1 != -1){
            s1.setSelection(prefsInt1);
        }



        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (parent.getId()){
                    case R.id.spinner1:{
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        editor.putInt(KEY_SavedSel, position);
                        editor.putInt(KEY_SavedSe2, position);
                        editor.commit();
                        if(india[position].equals("humains")){
                            ma.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            s1.setAdapter(ma);


                        }
                        if(india[position].equals("elfes")){

                            ba.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            s1.setAdapter(ba);


                        }
                        if(india[position].equals("hobbits")){

                            ua.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            s1.setAdapter(ua);


                        }

                    }


                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,

                        "Resultat : " +

                                "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(s.getSelectedItem()) +

                                "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem()),

                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });



    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: yes it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharedPreferences keys must be different otherwise the second spinner will override the value saved from the first spinner

eg.

```
final String KEY_SavedSel = "Saved Selection";
final String KEY_SavedSe2 = "Saved Selection2";
```

and then you can use it as below and retrieve the values later on in your code

```
    s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(KEY_SavedSel, position);
            editor.commit();

            if (india[position].equals("humains")) {
                ma.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s1.setAdapter(ma);


            }
            if (india[position].equals("elfes")) {

                ba.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s1.setAdapter(ba);


            }
            if (india[position].equals("hobbits")) {

                ua.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                s1.setAdapter(ua);

            }

            s1.setSelection(mypref.getInt(KEY_SavedSe2, -1));


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }


    });

    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt(KEY_SavedSe2, position);
            editor.commit();

            if (b[position].equals("Arwen")) {
                // TODO: Do something

            }
            if (b[position].equals("Elrond")) {
                // TODO: Do something


            }
            if (b[position].equals("Galadriel")) {
                // TODO: Do something

            }
            if (b[position].equals("Legolas")) {
               // TODO: Do something

            }




        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }


    });

}
```

And also you should add the following line

`s1.setSelection(mypref.getInt(KEY_SavedSe2, -1));`

inside your `s.setOnItemSelectedListener` as showed above because everytime the app restarts `s.setOnItemSelectedListener` is being called and it's not setting the second spinner selected item appropriately and by adding that there it will fix your initial issue.

Comment: thanks for yout answer this one it doesn't work, i did exactly what you said

Comment: @momo what are the values coming out from SharedPreferences when you try to retrieve it?

Comment: it gonna depend if exemple i selected humains in the first spinner the second spinner should have like values: PUNE","Mumbai","yoo". if i selected again from forst spinner elfes second spinner i got those choices: "Arwen","Elrond","Galadriel","Legolas"

Comment: first spinner i have 3 categories and i can save them easy but not the second one

Comment: s is my first, s1 is my second

Comment: got it, I think the problem has no relationship with the saving on sharedPreferences, because I far as I understood your problem you are trying to update the values in the second spinner when user select a value on the first one, right? I updated my answer could you try it out?

Comment: i can update the values but i can't save the values i chosed in the second spiner,in the forst one i can, for example i chosed the human in the first spiner in the second spinner i got the choices i want but i can't save the second spinner that's my probleme while i quit the app, i dont know if you understand what i mean thanks

Comment: I updated the code. I tested here and its working, try it out

Comment: ohh you sure it saves the both of the spiner when you restart the app?

Comment: here i want to save do you know how can i save?  if (b[position].equals("Arwen")) {

                }
                if (b[position].equals("Elrond")) {
                    // TODO: Do something
                    

                }
                if (b[position].equals("Galadriel")) {
                    // TODO: Do something

                }
                if (b[position].equals("Legolas")) {
                    // TODO: Do something

                }

Comment: Same way as you did on the first spinner. The code to save is already added on my answer.

Comment: I tested here and it's working. Anyway, I update my answer, place the code I just added in your button onclickListener so you can test it properly.

Comment: ye that's what i did still the same problem

Comment: Apparently, we have the same code and yours it's not working. is your project on GitHub? then I could take a look?

Comment: this is the link drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lQHT6nZq-1vZNsGzh5lAE_nnF38G9eEj

Comment: try to join the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160750/sharedpreferences-on-spinner)

Comment: did you check the link because they dont leave me to jin the chat message: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: I see... Check the code in the link following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i6z93zrppg4oah/Persos.zip?dl=0) 
and watch the toast and the logcat it updates correctly

Comment: for you when you quit the app and then you restart it  you got the same spinners that you have chosed before, beaucouse me i got juste the forst spinner the second one it backs to the first value all time?

Comment: Okay, finally got it. Please check my updated answer. I added a line inside the method s.setOnItemSelectedListener(). check on this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7i6z93zrppg4oah/Persos.zip?dl=0) as well

Comment: yeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeees bro you re the boss finally i sewear it took me like 6h haha thx a lot for your time

Comment: No worries, you are welcome! but next keep you use spinners keep in mind that if you call spinner.setSelection() the listener will also be called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take two different keys :

both of followings are same :

```
final String KEY_SavedSel = "Saved Selection";
final String KEY_SavedSe2 = "Saved Selection";
```

Change them as follows :

```
final String KEY_SavedSel = "Saved Selection1";
final String KEY_SavedSe2 = "Saved Selection2";
```

and while setting adapter you have not considered item selection of spinner2. you need to put value for spinner 2 as well. add following case as well.

```
     case R.id.spinner2:{
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                  //  editor.putInt(KEY_SavedSel, position);

                 // your remaining code.

                    editor.putInt(KEY_SavedSe2, position);
                    editor.commit();
                    }
```

Comment: no i did exaclty what you said still works for the first spinner but the second one it doesn't